# How to add dynamic icon to the Listview as per condition?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to add dynamic icon to the listview. applying dynamic icon to listview is depend on data which is coming from server so data is like following

> [{"name":"","id":"8","status":"one"},
>   {"name":"A","id":"9","status":"two"},
>   {"name":"A","id":"10","status":"three"}]

suppose status is "one" then apply color to View element is red and status is "two" then apply color
 to view is blue and etc. so following is the my code structure

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/bangDetVwStatusIcon"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@color/booked_color" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bangDetTitle"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bangDetImgVwNavigationDn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

code
    ListAdapter  bunglowAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
                    R.layout.expandable_list_item, R.id.bangDetTitle, bungLowList){

```
            public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                statusIcon = (View)v.findViewById(R.id.bangDetVwStatusIcon);

                if (getItem(position).equals("booked")) {


                    statusIcon.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                }
                if (getItem(position).equals("onhold")) {


                    statusIcon.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                }
                if (getItem(position).equals("available")) {


                    statusIcon.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                }

                return v;
            }   
        };
```

i tried lot but not achieve my goal. can anybody have solution then please suggest me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is in `bungLowList`

Comment: @Selvin ohh yes you are right...

Comment: bungLowList is an array which is contain name and this name display on listview.

Comment: They're all being set to the same colour: R.color.booked_color...

Comment: sorry please see my updated question and suggest me answer.